# Migrating a Grails application to Scala Play/Spray

Tags: scala, grails, playframework

We have a moderately sized Grails web application using GORM/Hibernate over PostgreSQL and GSPs serving HTML, and also a few REST APIs. We are standardising on Scala, and would like to migrate this application to Play or Spray, with Slick to access the existing database.

[Nimble](http://grails.org/plugin/nimble) is currently used for authentication/authorisation and user/role/etc. management.

What are the approaches we can take in order to do the migration step by step, avoiding a big bang migration?

They are both JVM languages, is there a way to avoid treating them as separate web apps running on separate ports at arms length?

Comment: Fun with project names, but a reasonable approach could be to use an application proxy to provide a single namespace.  Another option is to run them as separate WAR files in a web container like Tomcat.  I've not done Grails or Scala, but if the web APIs are a wrapper around Java Servlets then you are golden.  If not, you'll have to use the app proxy to hide the separate ports, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, a rewrite sounds more efficient to me, but if you need to do it in stepwise pieces I would suggest you take the following approach:

- Move your existing database code to use Slick (you'll probably need wrappers around it to shield your existing code from too many changes).
- Next, integrate Play into your runtime and use Silhouette for authentication and authorization with Play Actions.
- You should then be able to move individual GSPs to Play/Twirl one at a time.

Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to make them listen to the same port so you'd have to redirect from Grails to the Play port in order to make it seamless.